# Select paragraphs w/o images

Tags: css, selector, paragraph

So here's sample HTML:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
<p><img src="catpic.jpg" /></p>
```

How can I apply `text-indent` to all paragraphs if paragraph doesn't contain any images.

In this case only 1st two elements would be selected.

```
p [insert magic] { text-indent: 2em; }
```

I can use CSS3, but I don't want to use JavaScript. Also, I can't add extra classes or anything to existing elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it, this involves going down the DOM tree to see if an image exists, and then back up to give a text-indent to the paragraph.

I think your best bet is to give all `p` tags a text-indent, and then give the `img` a negative `margin-left` of the same value